# GridbagLayout horizontal fill

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I use gridbaglayout to dynamically construct the JPANEL  from an array of label and button. And i want the label to stretch its width as the panel dimension is been changed by user. I have the weightx and fill constraints and still this is not working. This inner Gridbaglayout panel is been enclosed by an another outer panel of grid layout.

Thanks in advance for your comments and suggestions.

Below is the SC for this case -

```
JPanel flowpanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
JPanel boxPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,0));

int valueCount =8;

void labelPropertySetter(JLabel label, JButton button, String name) throws IOException {
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,55));
    label.setText(name);
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,55)); 
    button.setName(name);
    button.setText(name);
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    DemoPanel dp  = new DemoPanel();
    JLabel[] numberLabel = new JLabel[dp.valueCount];
    JButton[] button = new JButton[dp.valueCount];

    for (int i=0;i<dp.valueCount;i++) {
        try {
                //jpanel[i]= new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0,0));
                numberLabel[i]=new JLabel();
                button[i]=new JButton();
                button[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setVisible(false);
                        System.out.println(((JButton)e.getSource()).getName());

                    }
                });

                dp.labelPropertySetter(numberLabel[i], button[i], new StringBuilder("Name :").append(i).toString());
                //dp.boxPanel.add(jpanel[i]);
            }
         catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    for(int i=0;i<dp.valueCount;i++)
    {
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=i;
        gbc.gridheight=1;
        gbc.gridwidth=1;
        gbc.weightx=1.0;
        gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        dp.flowpanel.add(numberLabel[i], gbc);

        gbc.gridx=2;
        gbc.gridy=i;
        gbc.gridheight=1;
        gbc.gridwidth=1;
        gbc.weightx=0;
        gbc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        dp.flowpanel.add(button[i], gbc);   
    }
    dp.boxPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    dp.boxPanel.add(dp.flowpanel);
    dp.add(dp.boxPanel);

    dp.pack();
    dp.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code that you're trying

Comment: shared the code that was tried.

Comment: That code won't compile. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. But please post an MCVE as suggested by @camickr. Most of us won't spend time trying to debug uncompilable code snippets.